# Is Deadpool censored?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, alternate-version, censorship, deadpool

I wanted to know if there's more than one version of Deadpool (censored or not) and if it is the exact same movie, except for language differences, in every country.

Comment: The answer to this is absolutely yes... but until it comes out in all countries, differences will be impossible to say... also, this is really broad. If you have one or two specific countries, that would help but every country has a different set of rules for films, so what India censors (if it even allows the film to screen) will be different from what appears in China or France... etc.

Comment: I think the downvotes on this question are a bit uncalled for. I would very much like to see a censored version of Deadpool. I don't think the question is too broad - I would imagine there are at most a dozen variants of the film, and a well-researched answer could easily cover all of them.

Comment: this question is a bit broad, as there could be multiple versions of the movie, depending on which countries choose to dub/subtitle it.  what, in particular, are you trying to figure out?

Comment: Unrelated to the original perhaps, but *Deadpool 2* is getting a re-release in a more family-friendly cut named *Once Upon a Deadpool*

Answer (score 3):

The main theatrical release of Deadpool in the U.S. was targeted to be Rated R by the MPAA. It's been said that it pushes the boundaries of what's allowed to be Rated R.

[The actor T.J. Miller, who plays Weasel in the film, has already confirmed that there will be an unrated cut for home release](https://tr.im/8zn0k):

> Twitter user by the name of James (From Essex) uploaded a quick six-second video of actor/comedian T.J. Miller at a recent screening confirming that an unrated director's cut of DEADPOOL starring Ryan Reynolds will be coming out on Blu-ray and dvd. The film will apparently be "even more raw" compared to the R-rated version.

<s>So you have to wait for the post-theatrical DVD/Blu-Ray/VOD releases to see the for reals real ***uncensored*** version.</s>

### ***Update:*** [Director Tim Miller has publicly stated there is no Director's cut planned:](http://collider.com/deadpool-directors-cut/)

> This is coming from the director himself, Tim Miller, who addressed the question last week during a Q&A at Collider’s exclusive IMAX preview screening of the film:
>
> **“I don’t wanna be all Joss Whedon on you, but no there’s not [a director’s cut]... There are some deleted scenes that have some extra stuff, but I’m pretty happy with this cut. I like it.**”

Deleted scenes, but no singular uncensored cut. What you see in the US theatrical release is what you get.

*Of course, this could always change, tomorrow or a week from now when initial box office numbers are in (Highest Revenue R-Rated movie released, ever), months from now when the DVD hits, or years from now for any re-releases.*